# Prisma + MongoDB M-to-N delete operation persist related id

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

I'm using Prisma + MongoDB. I have this prisma schema, note that are many-to-many related:

```js
model Product {
  id          String   @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  Pos         Pos[]    @relation(fields: [posIds], references: [id])
  posIds      String[] @db.ObjectId
}

model Pos {
  id            String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt
  products      Product[] @relation(fields: [productIds], references: [id])
  productIds    String[]  @db.ObjectId
}
```

I create a pos:

```js
    const pos: Pos = await prisma.pos.create({
      data: {
        products: {
          connect: productIds?.map((productId) => ({ id: productId })),
        },
      }
    })
```

Delete a product:

```js
    const productDeleted: Product | null = await prisma.product.delete({
      where: {
        id: productId,
      }
    })
```

The problem I'm facing is when I delete a product, that product id remains in pos.productIds, currently I'm removing it manually. Is there a way to solve this automatically with Prisma? Note that products array inside pos are correctly updated in this case (the problem is in productIds array). Thanks in advance.

This is the solution I'm using for now:

```js
const productDeleted: Product | null = await prisma.product.delete({
      where: {
        id: productId,
      }
    })
    
    const affectedPosRecords = await prisma.pos.findMany({
      where: { productIds: { has: productId } },
    })

    for (const posRecord of affectedPosRecords) {
      await prisma.pos.update({
        where: { id: posRecord.id },
        data: {
          productIds: {
            set: posRecord.productIds.filter((id) => id !== productId),
          },
        },
      })
    }
```